# Why does my EF Core convention create tables twice when scripting?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement ([github link](https://github.com/jeffreyabecker/efcore-tabularhilo-wtf/blob/so-question/why-double-create)) a table-based HiLo sequence generator and seeing unexpected behavior. I'm using an `IModelFinalizingConvention` to add a shadow entity to the model. When generating migrations, the Migration and ContextModelSnapshot show the code I expect.

However when I execute a `dotnet ef migrations script`, the [generated SQL file](https://github.com/jeffreyabecker/efcore-tabularhilo-wtf/blob/so-question/why-double-create/ConsoleApp2/out.sql) includes duplicate create statements for my underlying table.

I've tried:

- Changing my table name so that it doesn't start with '__EF'
- Changing the database provider (it does this with both SQL Server and SQLite)

Answer (score 0):

EF Core use a internal model to manage migration. But this internal model reuse conventions, like your convention that add the custom entity. Then EF Core to apply two model with the same entity and create two table with the same name in DB.

Sound like a bug, but I need more time to dig... time I haven't now.

---

As a temporally solution, you can add your custom table only when it's necessary :

```cs
if (!modelBuilder.Metadata.GetEntityTypes().Any(e => e.Name == entityName))
{
    var sequences = modelBuilder.Metadata.GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(HasHiLoSequence)
        .Select(GetSequenceInfo)
        .ToList();

    // Add the entity only when the model need sequences
    if (sequences.Any())
    {
        var sequencesEntity = modelBuilder.Entity(entityName);
        ...
    }
}
```

As the migration model don't use sequence, so the custom entity isn't added in the migration model.

---

I hope somebody will post a better explanation and solution.. or I'll give a try in a few days.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work sadly. I'm going to dig into the ef codebase around script generation and see if I cant figure out how to debug into my code while scripting sql out.

Comment: I tested and it work. Can you update the GitHub project with the modification?